# Error while sorting using Collections sort

Tags: java

When running the below code I get an error. I need suggestion on how to solve the error.

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("test", "milan");
map.put("joo", "arsenal");
map.put("keer", "manu");

List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return (((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue()).compareTo((Map.Entry) (o2)));
    }
});
```

Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Node cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing `String` with `Map.Entry` in `comapre` Use `((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())`,

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        return (((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue()));

    }
});
```

You can make your code more readable as,

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Comparator return line, it should be:

```
return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue()).compareTo((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
```

The reason is you forgot to get Value from o2

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Collections.sort()` you should use `list.sort()` for sorting a list.

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> list = new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());
list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

Comment: Why? How does this fix the issue? You could literally do the same with `Collections.sort(list, Map.Entry.comparingByValue())`, in fact `list.sort(...)` is nothing more than a plain redirect.